# Why does super().__dict__ raise an AttributeError?

Tags: python, magic-methods, python-descriptors

Why is this raising an AttributeError?

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        print(super().__dict__)

A().f()  # raises AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

Comment: Python raises an `AttributeError` whenever you try to access an attribute that doesn't exist

Comment: The superclass of `A` is `object`, which indeed does not have a `__dict__`.  (If it did, then *every* object would have a `__dict__`, which would be undesirable.)

Comment: Both `object.__dict__` and `type.__dict__` do not return an AttributeError in my interactive Python session

Comment: But `object().__dict__` does raise an `AttributeError`

Answer (score 1):

`super()` delegates attribute access to the next class in MRO. In this case, `object` is an implicit parent class. Instances of `object` class do not contain the `__dict__` attribute:

```py
object().__dict__  # raises AttributeError
```

However, instances of empty classes do contain the `__dict__` attribute, so if `A` inherits from an empty base class, no error is raised:

```py
class Foo:
    pass


class A(Foo):
    def f(self):
        print(super().__dict__)

A().f()  # prints '{}'
```

Comment: The docs of super state that it delegates the calls to the parent class (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super). However, `object()` is not the parent class itself, but an instance of the parent class. Is the doc wrong here?

Answer (score -3):

I think attribute error comes many times with no reason , it happened with me so many times ....
The Only solution is that this method is no longer usable try to go though docs or use another one .